# MySQl query conflict on server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have below query running correctly on my local server but not on live server.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_cr_booking WHERE product_id ='182' AND CURDATE() <= end AND STATUS !=1 AND CURDATE() between START and END ORDER BY ID
```

LIVE SERVER:

As you can seen, it should not return the row since I want only to fetch data between Start and End for current date?

[image]

LOCAL SERVER:

The same query is working fine on local system with same database:

[image]

Comment: Compare the result of CURDATE() in Local and Live server.

Comment: ah great it is different. The liver server shows 2015/06/07 and local  2015/06/08

Comment: TimeZone of Local and Live server may different. So only the time differs.